# associate two column together

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL statement:

```
select DISTINCT id_etudiant,g1.id_cours,note
from etudiant NATURAL JOIN inscription NATURAL JOIN groupe g1,groupe g2
where g1.id_cours = g2.id_cours
group by id_etudiant,g1.id_cours,note
having count(g1.id_cours) > 1
order by id_etudiant asc
;
```

Which gives this result:

```
ID_ETUDIANT   ID_COURS   NOTE
----------- ----------   ----
    1            8        E
    2            1        A
    2            2        A
    2            3        B
    3            1        B
    3            1        E
    3            2
    3            3        B
    8            8        E
    8            8
```

so my question is, how do I obtain this result instead?

```
ID_ETUDIANT   ID_COURS     NOTE
-----------   --------     ----
     3             1        B
     3             1        E
     8             8        E
     8             8
```

i'm not good how to ask a question i'm sorry about this

Comment: Perhaps adding `WHERE id_etudiant IN (3,8)`.

Comment: Please tell us what qualifies the rows in the expected output - why are they included and the other rows excluded?

Comment: explain to us the data that you are starting with and then explain (words, not code really) what you are trying to end up with.  such as... why isn't `A` returned?

Comment: if i take example 3 and 8, they have 2 times the same id_cours and the others dont, the column are like, student_id, class_id,grade

Comment: and i can't specify the id_etudiant like 3 and 8. In the case that another id_etudiant had twice the same id_cours, i would have want it

Comment: You should learn the proper `join` syntax. `from etudiant NATURAL JOIN inscription NATURAL JOIN groupe g1,groupe g2
where g1.id_cours = g2.id_cours` is wrong. You are mixing implicit and explicit joins. Which then creates a cartesian product because you are not joining the `groupe` table(s) against the `student` or `inscription` table. I'm surprised Oracle doesn't reject the `NATURAL JOIN groupe g1,groupe g2` part. (And stay away from `natural join`!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your responses in the comments, I believe you want the rows where an etudiant has the same cours more than once.

I think the problem with the query you have is that it includes note. Try this simplified version:

```
select DISTINCT id_etudiant,g1.id_cours
from etudiant NATURAL JOIN inscription NATURAL JOIN groupe g1,groupe g2
where g1.id_cours = g2.id_cours
group by id_etudiant,g1.id_cours
having count(g1.id_cours) > 1
order by id_etudiant asc
;
```

If it gives the correct rows, then add note back in at the end:

```
select table1.id_etudiant, table1.id_cours, table2.note 
from ( 
select DISTINCT id_etudiant,g1.id_cours
from etudiant NATURAL JOIN inscription NATURAL JOIN groupe g1,groupe g2
where g1.id_cours = g2.id_cours
group by id_etudiant,g1.id_cours
having count(g1.id_cours) > 1
) as table1, 
left outer join inscription as table2 
on table1.id_etudiant = table2.id_etudiant and table1.id_cours = table2.id_cours
order by id_etudiant, id_cours
;
```

This would be easier if there were sample table structures and data to work from.

Comment: Hi user3380481, you accepted this answer, but please take note of the comment above from @a_horse_with_no_name. I would not have written the query the way you had it in the first place, but left it largely unchanged in my answer so it would be clear what I added to get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your original query (I skipped the DISTINCT because it is not nessessary) and under the assumption that you want only the rows with the same etudiant and cours but different note, this query may help you:

```
SELECT id_etudiant, id_cours, note
  FROM(
     SELECT id_etudiant, g1.id_cours, note,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_etudiant, g1.id_cours) cnt
       FROM etudiant 
    NATURAL 
       JOIN inscription 
    NATURAL 
       JOIN groupe g1, groupe g2
      WHERE g1.id_cours = g2.id_cours
      GROUP 
         BY id_etudiant, g1.id_cours, note
     HAVING COUNT(g1.id_cours) > 1
      )
 WHERE cnt > 1     
 ORDER 
    BY id_etudiant ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT() OVER() like this:

```
select
      ID_ETUDIANT, ID_COURS, NOTE
from (
      select
              ID_ETUDIANT, ID_COURS, NOTE
            , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_ETUDIANT, ID_COURS) as x
      from existing_query
      ) 
where x > 1
```

Which will produce:

```
| ID_ETUDIANT | ID_COURS |   NOTE |
|-------------|----------|--------|
|           3 |        1 |      B |
|           3 |        1 |      E |
|           8 |        8 |      E |
|           8 |        8 | (null) |
```